# How to link ms-access with vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hello sir with this post i m sending my code    enter code here

```
Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Info.accdb")
Dim CommandStringX As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1"
Dim myadapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(CommandStringX, conn)
Dim cmdbuilderX = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myadapter)
myadapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(CommandStringX, conn)
myadapter.InsertCommand = cmdbuilderX.GetInsertCommand
myadapter.UpdateCommand = cmdbuilderX.GetUpdateCommand 'not needed now
myadapter.DeleteCommand = cmdbuilderX.GetDeleteCommand 'not needed now
myadapter.Fill(dtset)
Try
    conn.Open()
    myadapter.FillSchema(dtset, SchemaType.Mapped) 'make your dataset tables like the ones in your Access database
    dtset.Tables("Table1").Rows(0)("Phone Number") = txtPhoneNumber.Text
    dtset.Tables("Table1").Rows(0)("Message") = txtMsg.Text
    myadapter.Update(dtset) 'Update Access database based on dtset
Catch ex As OleDbException
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try
```

MY problem is that i hav created database and it is empty with specific colums defined by me but there is no data after defining that columns ... i want to store data at runtime so when i execute that it shows me an error like this " null refernce exception was unhandled " at this line

```
dtset.Tables("Table1").Rows(0)("Phone Number") = txtPhoneNumber.Text
```

Please help regarding this

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute a sql insert statement to push data into your tables.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no data in the table, then there's no row to access.  Thus, the object which is not set in that line is `Rows(0)`.  You can't reference the first row in the collection if there are no rows to reference.

It looks like what you're trying to do is add a row to `Table1` in your DataSet.  [Here's some information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) on how to do that.  Essentially, the steps are:

- Create a new DataRow using the schema present in the DataTable.
- Populate that row with data.
- Add that row to the Rows collection in the DataTable.

Comment: thank you sir i have seen ur link but  one confusion the page u linked is helpful for entering null database means can i store data @ runitme in empty database pardon for my question but i m new in this field ... Thank you again waiting for ur reply

Comment: @Harshit: As you can imagine, there's a language barrier here so it's unclear exactly what you're asking.  In your code it looks like you're trying to copy a database schema to your DataSet, add rows to your DataSet, and update it back to the database.  The problem is when you add rows.  You're trying to access the first element in the `.Rows` collection, which has no elements.  Thus, the exception being thrown.  You need to create a `DataRow` object, add your data to that, and add that to the `.Rows` collection.

Comment: @david: sir thank you .... i'll try if any question den i'll ask to u.. Thank you very much

Comment: @david:sir i m not able to do that with the link given by you .... any other idea about this or will u please provide me ur e-mail id so that i can mail u my whole project for ur better understanding ?????

Comment: @Harshit: My email? No. However, you can update your question with any additional relevant information and updated code. How are you now trying to add data given my suggestion? The original error in the original code is still clear... You can't access the first element in an empty array.

Comment: sir i've trid dis code:Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Info.mdb")
Dim myCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
con.Open()                                            myCommand.CommandText = "Insert into Table1([PhoneNumber],[Message]) values('" & txtPhoneNumber.Text & "','" & txtMsg.Text & "')" myCommand.Connection = con
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
i'm goin wid dis code nw i thoght it might b compatible bt it shows error on
Code:myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() The error shows overflow on dat line "oledb ecxeption was unhandled"

Comment: @Harshit: That code looks like it should insert a record into `Table1` in the database.  (Note, not in the `DataSet` object, just in the database.)  The error seems to indicate that there is a more useful error that's not being shown.  What is the resulting query after the string concatenation?  Does that query run in the database manually without error?  I'd also like to note that using string concatenation in SQL queries is very bad practice for a number of reasons.  You'll want to look into parameterized queries for both security and performance reasons.